# Installing JGR (GUI for R) on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, user-interface, r

I am getting the following error when I try to run jgr-x64.exe on Windows 7 64-bit.

Couldn't install JGR!
Please re-install R and/or connect to the internet

My Packages are getting installed at

> \AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp886Wzb\downloaded_packages

Is it something to do with setting environmental variables?

Any advise on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-standard R library locations, you need to tell jgr-x64.exe where to look for the JGR package. Some instructions on how to do this are at: http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.RunningJGRWithANon-standardRInstallation

The newest development version of JGR can automatically create a script to do this for you. You can test it out by doing the following:

```
install.packages("JGR",,"http://www.rforge.net",type="source")
library(JGR)
JGR()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the R prompt, **you must be in a directory where you have write access** (run as admin if necessary, or else `setwd()` to your preferred directory) when you run `JGR()` for the first time. This will download jgr-1_62-x64.exe and create a jgrLaunch.bat file tailored to your system. It defines environment variables and command-line options to jgr-1_62-x64.exe.

You can move these files (e.g. to the desktop) after creation; just note that jgrLaunch.bat calls jgr-1_62-x64.exe, so the latter must either be in PATH or in the same directory as the .bat file.